# Result of/from something

Tags: word-choice, word-difference

> Surprisingly, a feeling of tiredness may result of a lack of exercise.

Take for example the sentence above. Should I use `result of` or `result from`? What is the difference?
Is there a general rule for the use of result of and result from?

Comment: Fyi the opposite would be: lack of exercise may *result in* a feeling of tiredness.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a verb, *result* takes *from*, not *of*. (in fact there are very few verbs that take *of* for one of their arguments - I can't think of any)*.

As a noun, *result* usually takes *of*, rather than *from*.

**Edit**: Fumblefingers pointed out that in saying I couldn't think of any examples, I used one! But on reflection, I don't think it is a counterexample: *think of* is a phrasal verb, with a different meaning from *think*.

Comment: I was going to write an answer but this was already accepted. Anyway, as a noun, "Surprisingly, a feeling of tiredness may be *the result of* a lack of exercise."

Comment: [*Adam **ate of** the fruit of the tree of knowledge.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Adam+ate+of+the+fruit+of+the+tree+of+knowledge%22) But if the best I can come up with is an antiquated biblical quote, you're probably quite right that there aren't many such verbs!

Comment: I thought of that, @Fumblefingers; but I don't think that _ate_ governs _of_ there: I think _of_ is either a locative (_from_ in modern English) or partitive (_some of_), but in the first case an adjunct, not an argument, and in the second a specifier within the NP.

Comment: *You certainly **thought of** a good example there.* :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: well noticed. So there is at least one!